# Multiple email validation regex with semicolon in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Multiple email validation regex with semicolon in Javascript

It can allow mulptiple emails and can allow the semicolon after email id. If only one email id provided then it can allow with or without semicolon.

I tried below code:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    function myFunction() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var reg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)+([;]([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+))*$/;
        if (reg.test(email) == false) {
            alert("Entered email id is not valid")
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("Entered email id is valid")
            return true;
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: If semicolon don't appear in email then just use `split(';')` and validated each email separately. It can have semicolon in obscure example of email, according to standard, but in your case you have simple email validation, so it should work for your case.

Comment: Hi Rahool. The code above seems to do what you want it to do, please can you be more specific about what is wrong?

Comment: I tried and got this solution:var reg= /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)+([;]*(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+))*)*$/;

Comment: That's far too restrictive. Your regex rejects many valid email addresses.

Comment: First split on `;` then have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

It splits email list into individual addresses and loops over all of them. Also, it uses much simplified regex to check email validity.

Also, checking for validity of one email on the list should be more robust, this is only an example.

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
console.log("Are emails valid: " + checkEmailValidity(email));

function checkEmailValidity(emailList) {
    var reg = /^.+?@.+?\.\w{2,}$/i;
    var emailArr;

    if (emailList.indexOf(";") < emailList.indexOf("@")) {
        //assume only one email address on the list
        emailArr = [emailList];
    } else {
        emailArr = emailList.split(";")
    }

    var isValid = true;
    emailArr.forEach(function(addr) {
        if (reg.test(addr) === false) {
            console.log("One of the emails is not valid: " + addr);
            isValid = false;
        }
    })
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: One caveat: it rejects valid emails in form `username@100.100.100.1`